# How to use WCF services in Windows 10 Universal App?

Tags: c#, wcf, win-universal-app, uwp

My Windows 8.1 app uses WCF services. I need to port my app to Windows 10 UWP app. But cannot add service reference. This message appears when I add a service reference:

> Data service client code-generation failed. Specified Windows Store Framework '.NETCore,Version=v5.0' is not supported. Only .NETCore 4.5 and above is supported.

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for @gregkalapos

**1. Create Windows 8.1 Portable class library** 
[image]

**2. Choose like this**

[image]

**3. Add Service Reference to newly created library. Then reference library to Windows 10 Universal App project.**

[image]

This is example call method:

```
var client = new ConnectODataEntities(new Uri("http://...ODATA URL..."));
var dsQuery = (DataServiceQuery<YOUR_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE>)(client.YOUR_METHOD);

var tf = new TaskFactory<IEnumerable<YOUR_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE>>();
var list = (await tf.FromAsync(dsQuery.BeginExecute(null, null),
                            iar => dsQuery.EndExecute(iar))).ToList();



lbox.ItemsSource = list;
```

> This method used app works on `Windows 10` and `Windows 10 Mobile`

Answer (score 3):

I also have this problem. The workaround I used was that I created a Portable Class Library targeting only Windows Runtime and added the service reference into that and I referenced the PLC in the UWP app. Btw. I think this is a known bug...