# Odata on UWP Client ignore ssl

Tags: windows, ssl, odata, uwp

On UWP client, HttpClient ignore ssl can use HttpBaseProtocolFilter, like

```
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent;
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Expired);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);

Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient webhttpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter);
```

But, how can i use odata on uwp client and ignore ssl?

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri(baseUriStr);
Container container = new Container(baseUri);
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To consume OData service in UWP app, we can use the workaround in this question: [How to use WCF services in Windows 10 Universal App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844768/how-to-use-wcf-services-in-windows-10-universal-app)

1. Create a **Windows 8.1 Portable class library** and change Target to
   **Windows 8.1**
   [image]
2. Add Service Reference in this PCL
   [image]
3. Add reference to the PCL in UWP app
4. Call Service like this:

   ```
   static void DisplayProduct(ClassLibrary2.ServiceReference1.Product product)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
   }

   // Get an entire entity set.
   static async void ListAllProducts(ClassLibrary2.ServiceReference1.Container container)
   {
       var dsQuery = container.Products;

       var tf = new TaskFactory<IEnumerable<ClassLibrary2.ServiceReference1.Product>>();
       var list = (await tf.FromAsync(dsQuery.BeginExecute(null, null),
                                   iar => dsQuery.EndExecute(iar))).ToList();
       foreach (var p in list)
       {
           DisplayProduct(p);
       }
   }

   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:18441/odata");
       var container = new ClassLibrary2.ServiceReference1.Container(uri);

       ListAllProducts(container);
   }
   ```

I created the testing OData service by following this document: [Creating an OData v3 Endpoint with Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/creating-an-odata-endpoint)

**Check my completed sample in here:** [Github Link](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/UWPCallODataServiceDemo)