# How to consume a WCF Data Service from UWP Application?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, wcf-data-services

I created a new ASP.Net site, added a WCF Data Service class, connected to database, all working.

I tested on WPF I can add this Service Reference without problem.

The problem is when I try to connect to this WCF Data Service from UWP, the add service reference to a WCF Data Service 5.6.4, then this error appears:

> Data service client code-generation failed. Specified Windows Store Framework '.NETCore,Version=v5.0' is not supported. Only .NETCore 4.5 and above is supported.

On WPF it works as expected. Why on UWP it does not work as expected? What is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632282/how-to-make-a-uwp-that-will-work-with-the-default-wcf-service-application

Comment: On step 4 of that answer the error appears when connect to a WCF Data Service 5.6.4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use WCF services in Windows 10 Universal App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844768/how-to-use-wcf-services-in-windows-10-universal-app)

Answer (score 0):

For WCF data service, the "add service reference" operation should not be a right way.

You could see this document [Using a Data Service in a Client Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728282(v=vs.110).aspx). It shows that using HTTP actions to perform create, read, update, and delete operations on the entity data that the addressed resource represents.